# How i should convert my selenium automation (Testng) project into a bat file or any executable file

Tags: batch-file, selenium, testng, exe

I have a project where i have used selenium to automate my web application using testng i need to run the same using a .bat file which i can directly execute using command line or integrate the same in jenkins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1**.You can create a single executable jar file for your project. However this jar requires a class with main()method to start the execution. Since here you are using testng, you need to execute it programmatically as below. You can execute this jar from command line as `java -jar filename.jar` OR write same command in batch file.

```
public class MainTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
      {
        TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
        TestNG testng = new TestNG();
        testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] { AnnotationTest.class });
        testng.addListener(tla);
        testng.run();
     }
}
```

**2**. If it is maven project, then maven provides  plugins to create single executable jar file for you. Make sure you refer testng.xml file in your project's pom.xml file.
Maven plugin for example : [Maven Shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html)

Please note, in both cases you need to have class with main()method.

Comment: Is your project a simple java project or maven project? you will get many blogs providing step by step solutions  if you search accordingly OR here is direct link on SO question [How to make a jar file for project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258159/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-file)

Comment: but @Mk08 it shows configuration failure in my testng. my project is not a maven project. I have a testng.xml file. the above class is working fine when I am running this class from IDE and but after making jar it showing configuration issue

Comment: Actually above function is running the class but we need a code which can execute the testng.xml file

Comment: @Shubham Jain : Check the updated solution in this SO question : [testng.xml from main method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28942467/testng-how-do-i-run-a-custom-testng-xml-file-programmatically) .