# How to create executable jar from maven TestNg project that runs from TestNg.xml file

Tags: maven, selenium, testng

I have a selenium project that is built on Maven and TestNG. I can run tests from TestNg.xml (Run as TestNg). I don't have any Main() in my project. How can I create an executable jar of this project?

Comment: [This may help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32600691/5146424)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How i should convert my selenium automation (Testng) project into a bat file or any executable file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32600274/how-i-should-convert-my-selenium-automation-testng-project-into-a-bat-file-or)